# crypto could not be found within the project or in these directories node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/node_modules

Tags: javascript, react-native, cryptojs, metamask

I am getting this error

[Error: undefined Unable to resolve module crypto from /pathToProject/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/dist.browser/index.js: crypto could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/node_modules
node_modules

```js
  71 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  72 | exports.thirdparty = exports.hdkey = void 0;
> 73 | var crypto = __importStar(require("crypto"));
     |                                    ^
  74 | var ethereumjs_util_1 = require("ethereumjs-util");
  75 | var scrypt_js_1 = require("scrypt-js");
```

Some related dependencies :

```json
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.6.0",
    "@metamask/controllers": "^30.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "3.3.0",
    "eth-keyring-controller": "^7.0.2",
    "ethers": "^5.6.4",
    "react-native-aes-crypto": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-crypto": "2.1.2",
```

I am trying to use KeyringController from [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/KeyringController) and other controllers defined by MetaMask from [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/controllers)

Answer (score -1):

Module `crypto` is not part of react-native runtime by default.

You might need to follow the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto#install to set up the shim.

Comment: that library is been dead for 5 years !!!

Comment: @bmaggi sorry about that, I have used this module in one of my projects, and it worked seamlessly. However, since it has been deprecated, I suggest you follow the link https://github.com/tradle/react-native-crypto#deprecated to explore possible replacement options.